# Can I pull a daily sessions report from Kentico?

Tags: session, report, analytics, kentico

I am trying to pull a report that shows the amount of daily sessions. We are looking at a new analytics software that bills by the session-not page views. We need a report that counts how long an individual user stays on the site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no report by individual user within Kentico.  The analytics data is not tracked like that, it is aggregated.  If you have an EMS license you could create [custom activities](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/on-line-marketing-features/configuring-and-customizing-your-on-line-marketing-features/configuring-activities/adding-custom-activity-types), then create a report based on those custom activities per user/contact.

Comment: I don't need it for an individual user. I just need a total of how many sessions we have per day and the amount of time spent on the site.

Comment: @adison your question specifically states: "We need a report that counts how long an individual user stays on the site."  I'd suggest using Google Analytics for your need then.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to be unclear. I just meant that we need to see individual sessions but it doesn't have to be linked to a specific user. I would love to use Google Analytics but our IT department won't allow it.

Comment: Still don't believe this is available but I'd suggest looking through the Reporting app in Kentico and see if there is a report in there which gives you what you're looking for.